# Google Banner Ad is not displaying in Iphone x

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, iphone-x

[image][image]

please help me if anyone know it, its not displaying actual ad, just showing test ad, i am trying to display in simulator, is this not display in iphone X simulator, please suggest me

Comment: you cannot display Real add in simulator...Real Ad will be Display in Device only.In simulator you can see only Test Add.

Comment: is it working on any other simulator?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot display Real Ad in simulator. Real Ad will be Display in Device only. In simulator you can see only Test Add.

Comment: native ads are showing in simulator , but not banner ads are showing

Comment: please let me know what i am missing , if you know

Comment: You cant see Test Ad also?